# Linux terminal octal form of chmod

Tags: linux, chmod, octal

I want to set a directory to

```
-rwx r-x r-x
```

using the octal form of chmod

what should i type in the terminal after chmod?
and how do i calculate the digits in octal form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It goes like this:

```
rwx rwx rwx
421 421 421
```

so what you want is

```
rwx r-x r-x
421 4-1 4-1
  7   5   5
```

so you type

```
chmod 755 nameofdirectory
```

Comment: Thanks. i figured out the numbering system that you explained, but what does rwx and r-x stand for? what do they mean?

Comment: r is for read, w is for write, x is for execute (but for directories it is recycled to mean "can access files in this directory if you already know their names").  The triplets are for owning-user, owning-group, and everyone else, in that order.  I'm surprised you don't already know this if you're asking this question...

Comment: For a general tutorial on file permissions see here: http://www.unix.com/tips-tutorials/19060-unix-file-permissions.html  It's chatty and informal but I don't see anything factual in it that is incorrect (best ignore all the historical speculation, though, and you don't need to know any of the HP-UX-specific gunk anymore, for which let us all rejoice)

Comment: Oh, I guess one more clarification: the dashes just mean that the bit in that position is not set (so, for your directory, owning user can write, but no one else can).