# Set permission using octal notation

Tags: linux, unix, octal

I know that permission are set using `Chmod` but I am having a hard time understating how to convert an octal number into a permission.

for example

> `640` does this mean that the user has `rw-r----x`
>   permission? Becuase 4+2=6 and 4 = w and 0 = - ?
>
> I understand that `777` is wide open because the user has full control fo the file 4+2+1 = 7 rwx
>   permission the group has rwx and the second group has rwx permission
>   If I were to answer this question my answer would be. `rw-r----x` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's not actual octal notation you have there, but 3 bit-flags. 1 for x, 2 for w, 4 for r, iirc. Keep in mind that the umask is inverted

Comment: I'm trying to set the permission to `640` using octal notation @Vogel612

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux terminal octal form of chmod](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19085653/linux-terminal-octal-form-of-chmod)

Comment: No if you read what I asked I basically explained that I understand how it works I don't understand how 640 would work. @Dan Cornilescu

Comment: technically you're right, but check the accepted answer, IMHO it cleanly shows how conversions in both directions work.

Comment: @DanCornilescu I figured it out. I simply just had to write chmod 640 + the directory

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 digits. The first digit is the user permissions, the second digit is the group permissions, the third digit is everyone else's permissions.

Every digit is formed by adding a subset of of 4 (read), 2 (write), 1 (execute).

Thus 6 4 0 means the user (`6`) is allowed to read and write (`4 + 2`), the group (`4`) is allowed to read (`4`), and everyone else (`0`) has no permissions.

Answer (score 0):

`x` is 1, therefore the third triad is read as "1". 0 would have the third triad be `---`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a picture would be easier:

[Linux File Permissions](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/linux-pocket-guide/9780596806347/httpatomoreillycomsourceoreillyimages305342.png)

..I would post it here but I don't have the rep

Some Examples:

1. We want the User to be able to read, write and execute the file, the group to have read access and no access for everyone else:

> chmod 740 test_dir

2. We want the everyone to have full access to read, write and execute:

> chmod 777 test_dir